# Units in $B\otimes_{A}B$, where $B/A$ is a finite Galois extension of number rings

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory

I need information or directions to the literature regarding the structure of the group of units of $B\otimes_{A}B$, where $B/A$ is a finite Galois extension of rings of integers, say associated to a finite unramified Galois extension of number fields. I'm mostly interested in the general case where $A$ is *not* assumed to be a PID. Can anyone help? Judging by related questions and answers on MO, determining the structure of $(B\otimes_{A}B)^{*}$ would seem to be a very difficult open problem. Is it? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: I may be misremembering, but I believe that Chase-Harrison-Rosenberg's characterization includes that, for a $G$-Galois extension $A \to B$ of rings, there is an isomorphism $B \otimes_A B \to \prod_{\sigma \in G} B$ sending $x \otimes y \to (x \sigma(y))_{\sigma}$. As a result, I think the unit group should be a finite product of copies of the unit group of $B$.

Comment: @TylerLawson: Since a module-finite extension of Dedekind domains $A\to B$ is everywhere unramified if and only if ${\rm{disc}}(B/A)=A$, the fact that in the generically Galois case with Galois group $G$ the map $B \otimes_A B\to \prod_{\sigma \in G} B$ an isomorphism is "classical". Briefly, make $A$ a dvr by localizing, and then quotient by $m_A$ on both sides to reduce to the analogue where $A$ is a field and $B$ is finite product of Galois extensions. By $G$-transitivity on the set of factor fields we can assume $B$ is a field. Now the assertion is standard in Galois theory.

Comment: @TylerLawson, thanks for your effort. So,  $(B\otimes_{A}B)^{*}\simeq (B^{∗})^{n}$, where $n$ is the order of $G$? In particular, the action of $G$ is inmaterial? My question is motivated by the following problem: let $u\in B^{*}$. When is it true that $u\otimes u^{-1}\in (B\otimes_{A}B)^{*}$ is an $n$-th power in $(B\otimes_{A}B)^{*}$? Certainly, this is the case if $u\in A^{*}(B^{*})^{n}$. Are there any other $u$'s?

Comment: By $u\in A^{*}(B^{*})^{n}$ I mean $u=ab^{n}$, where $a\in A^{*}$ and $b\in B^{*}$